# How to set image size inside TabbedPanel in Kivy?

Tags: image, layout, kivy

I'm trying to set the size of an image which is a child item of the TabbedPanel.

[image]

How do I increase the size of the added image (which is small as seen above) and make it responsive to any screen resize events. Below is my code snippet.

**.kv**

```
TabbedPanel:
    do_default_tab: False
    tab_height:20
    tab_width: self.parent.width / 4
    TabbedPanelItem:
        text: "ONE"
        Image:
            src: "img.jpg"
            size: 400, 500
            allow_stretch: True
            keep_ratio: True
    TabbedPanelItem:
        text: "TWO"
        Image:
            src: " "
            size: 400, 500
            allow_stretch: True
            keep_ratio: True
```

Should the image widget be enclosed within another layout? Thanks for your time.

Comment: Replace `src:` with `source:`. What you have already defined for Image works fine.

Comment: Thank you for your reply. Changed to source, still have the same resizing issue..

Comment: Please check my post with example.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

## Solution

Please refer to the example for details.

1. Replace `src:` with `source:`.
2. Remove `size: 400, 500`

## Example

### main.py

```
from kivy.app import App
from kivy.uix.tabbedpanel import TabbedPanel
from kivy.lang import Builder

Builder.load_string("""

<Test>:
    do_default_tab: False
    tab_height:20
    tab_width: self.width / 4

    TabbedPanelItem:
        text: "ONE"
        Image:
            source: "brown-bear-150x150.jpg"
            allow_stretch: True
            keep_ratio: True

    TabbedPanelItem:
        text: "TWO"
        Image:
            source: "grizzly-bear-150x150.jpg"
            allow_stretch: True
            keep_ratio: True

    TabbedPanelItem:
        text: 'THREE'
        Image:
            source: "giant-panda-150x150.jpg"
            allow_stretch: True
            keep_ratio: True

    TabbedPanelItem:
        text: 'FOUR'
        Image:
            source: "polar-bear-150x150.jpg"
            allow_stretch: True
            keep_ratio: True


""")


class Test(TabbedPanel):
    pass


class TabbedPanelApp(App):
    def build(self):
        return Test()


if __name__ == '__main__':
    TabbedPanelApp().run()
```

## Output

[image: Img01]
[image: Img02]
[image: Img03]